# How to configure App Engine Flexible Environment to use Google Preemptible VMs instead of the normal one?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

The [Preemptible VMs](https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/) offers much lower cost compared to a normal VM, and the way preemptible VMs work seems to be similar to App Engine (short lived machines).

App Engine backend instances cost 0.05 USD/hour/instance for the lowest power and 128 MB RAM, but preemptible VMs cost only 0.01 USD/hour for much more CPU power and almost 4GB RAM.

However I can't seem to find a way for App Engine Flexible to run on preemptible VM. I can't find anything on `app.yaml` that enables it. Is it not supported?

Comment: Good question. I guess that's not possible, but I don't understand why Preemptible VM is not the default support.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently available.  You can follow this issue for updates:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13318&q=label%3AComponent-ManagedVMs&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log